# How to troubleshoot Gitlab-runner gitlab-ci.yml file job failure after the build process is complete?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have problem in Gitlab CI/CD build stage. For some reason the job is failing.
My Gitlab-Runner yaml file structure is below:

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

job 1:
  stage: build
  script:
    - 'bash lint.sh'
    - "echo test"
  allow_failure: true

job 2:
  stage: deploy
  script: "bash deploy.sh"
```

The problem is that after the lint.sh is executed, It returns the positive pylint score but the job is not succeeded in the job status and fails with the exit status:1 as shown in the image below:

[image: error image]

After checking the `logs` of `gitlab-runner`, I found the following error:

> pam_systemd(su:session): Failed to create session: Start job for unit
>   user@0.service failed with 'failed'

Log-Image:

[image: Log error]

Comment: Kindly add logs as text instead of images, It improves readability,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using pylint to check your score of the code that you've build, always remember that pylint will return exit status 1 each time even if it detects a single warning. So, try to resolve each caution/warning/error and re run the pipeline.